# What is the difference between -contains vs .contains in powershell script?

Tags: powershell

What is the difference between .contains and -contains? One seems case sensitive while the other one is not.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ("jack", "john", "jill").contains("Jill")
False


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> "jack", "john", "jill" -contains "Jill"
True
```

Why is there such a discrepancy?

Comment: Hi, I assume `.contains` will be called directly on the given object, but `-contains` will run some global function within powershell - probably implemented on the same place, where the previous is being called at the end..

Comment: The `-Contains` operator compares one object against a collection. It returns true if that entire value exists as an item in a collection. It is case-insensitive and is not limited to strings. `-CContains` is the case-sensitive version. The `.Contains()` method is a .NET method from the String class. It compares a substring against a string (case-sensitive by default).

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thank you. Could you add an answer so I can accept it? Do you mind also adding some links to the method documentations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-Contains` operator compares one object against a collection. It returns true if that entire value exists as an item in a collection. It is case-insensitive and is not limited to strings. `-CContains` is the case-sensitive version. The `.Contains()` method is a .NET method from the String class. It compares a substring against a string (case-sensitive by default).

Your first example could be manipulated to achieve the desired results if you convert your array into a string because `jill` will be a substring within the larger string.

```
("jack","jill","john" -join ",").Contains("jill")
True
```

See [About_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) for details and examples of using `-Contains`.
See [String.Contains Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) for an explanation of the `.Contains` method.

Comment: If you know where to look, could you please add some references to the documentation pages? I tried to Google it but was not successful to find the authoritative place. @AdminOfThings

Comment: @CEGRD I added them.

Answer (score 4):

Both are very different in actual.

```
$str = "abcde"

$str -contains "abcd" 
False

$str.Contains("abcd") 
True
```

**Why this difference?**

Because

> **-Contains** is a Containment operator as per MS. Tells
>   whether a collection of reference
>         values includes a single test value. Always returns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE
>         only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values.It must be one of the elements **include**(contains)
>   in the array not a substring of a string element
>
> **Contains() Method** is one of the methods of string object that supports
>   substring hence why you get True when you run
>   `$str.Contains("abcd")`

Hope it helps.